# Forced termination IOS App from multi task menu error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

When I run some tests on my app and try to terminate the app (in the simulator) from the multi task menu, it terminates. The issue is when I try to run it again by selecting it on my dock, it does not run. It freezes and it becomes this small little image in the corner of the simulator. I am wondering why this is happening and if there is certain code that needs to be programmed for situations like this so the app terminates "gracefully".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check your logic in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of the app delegate. Most likely, there is some initialization problem that leads to this behavior. Put breakpoint and `NSLog`s there (and perhaps also into other app delegate methods such as `applicationWillEnterForeground:`) to investigate what is happening.

Comment: I believe after doing some research is that when the user kills the app with the minus sign in the multi task bar menu, it doesn't remove the app or refresh. Now I am not sure whether that is true but I do know when the users does what is described above, it calls upon ApplicationWillTerminate. Do you know if something needs to be coded here for proper results? and if so, can you give me a brief explanation? Thanks

Comment: Yes: in `applicationWillTerminate:` you should **persist** all data that you need to **reconstruct** the state again from scratch (if this is the desired behavior). Make sure that the routines for starting up the app do not rely on some other data (database, files, user preferences, etc.) that conflict with re-initializing the app.